# If $\mathbb{Z}_a\oplus\mathbb{Z}_b\cong \mathbb{Z}_c\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d$, $a|b$, and $c|d$,  then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $a, b, c$ and $d$ are positive integers such that $b$ is an integer multiple of $a$, and $d$ is an integer multiple of $c$. How can we prove that

> **if the direct sums $ \mathbb Z_a\oplus \mathbb Z_b $ and  $\mathbb Z_c\oplus \mathbb Z_d $ are isomorphic  then $a=c$ and $b=d$.**

What I have done is:

If $b$ is multiple of $a$, then there exists an integer $m$ such that $ b=a\cdot m $. Similarly, if $d$  is an integer multiple of $c$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $ d=c\cdot n $

If $ \mathbb Z_a\oplus \mathbb Z_b $ and  $\mathbb Z_c\oplus \mathbb Z_d $ are isomorphic, then $ a\cdot b=c\cdot d $

Then we get $ a^2\cdot m= c^2\cdot n $ . But it seems like we can not get anything from this to reach the answer.

Comment: Consider the largest order of an element in either group.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_a$ is the cyclic group of $a$ elements? In your spot, the next thing I'd think to try is to use your equations to make a counter-example. (and if I can't, figure out why I fail) It might help to work one prime at a time -- i.e. $a,b,c,d$ all be powers of the same prime. (if you can do this, you can use Chinese Remainder Theorem or somesuch for the full answer)

Comment: @Henning Makholm: $\phi(b)=\phi(d)$ right?

Comment: @ArtiomFiodorov: _Additive_ order.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

1. If $a\mid b$, what is the largest order of any element of $\mathbb{Z}_a\oplus\mathbb{Z}_b$? Is this number an isomorphism invariant?
2. What is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_a\oplus\mathbb{Z}_b$?

Comment: if b=am then the largest order of any element of Za⊕Zb is am. Similarly if d=cn then the largest order of any element of Zc⊕Zd is  cn. Since they are isomorphic then am=cn. If Za⊕Zb and Zc⊕Zd are isomorphic, then a⋅b=c⋅d since the isomorphic groups have the same order. So, a^2.m=c^2.n and am=cn we can see that a=c.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help.